# Receive multiple objects for a POST request in Restfull WCF service with JSON

Tags: json, wcf, rest, post

Serialized 2 objects into a stream and attached it to HttpWebRequest

```
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(OBJECT1));
    ser.WriteObject(stream1, controller);
    ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(OBJECT2));
    ser.WriteObject(stream1, reader);
    stream1.position =0;
```

My json string looks like this (after above code) :
`{\"Object1Parameter1\":\"2\"}{\"Object2Parameter1\":\"Added reader\",\"Object2Parameter2\":\"2\"}`

Even tried adding parent to this string with name OBJECT1 and OBJECT2 resp, but still data did not get deserialized at server.

There is no problem in receiving the data like this at the Rest service

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "Controller")]
        string AddBothObjects(/*parameters of both objects listed*/);
```

How do I receive this data at the service end in both objects rather than individual parameters.
Something like this:

```
[OperationContract]
            [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
                UriTemplate = "Controller")]
            string AddBothObjects(Object1 obj1,Object2 obj2);
```

Comment: This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804588/wcf-rest-post-methos-not-work-with-c-sharp-winform-client-with-multiple-user-def
But, there was no response to that question

That is why posted as a seperate question with more details regarding to my scenario

Answer (score 0):

I think when you POST data to your WCF service, you should wrap all of the data you're sending into an object (1 request object). This is sample code to show what I'm talking about

Client:

```
            // declare ascii encoding
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            string jsonObject1 = "{\"Object1Parameter1\":\"2\"}";
            string jsonObject2 = "{\"Object2Parameter1\":\"Added reader\",\"Object2Parameter2\":\"2\"}";


            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(jsonObject1 + jsonObject2);

            string url = "http://localhost:64273/Sparql.svc/TestForStack";

            string strResult = string.Empty;

            // declare httpwebrequet wrt url defined above
            HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            // set method as post
            webrequest.Method = "POST";
            // set content type
            webrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // set content length
            webrequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
            // get stream data out of webrequest object
            Stream newStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream();

            newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            newStream.Close();

            //Gets the response
            WebResponse response = webrequest.GetResponse();
            //Writes the Response
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Service Interface

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "TestForStack",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    Stream TestForStack(Stream request);
```

Service Implementation

```
public Stream TestForStack(Stream request)
    {
        StreamReader requestReader = new StreamReader(request);

        //data contains "{\"Object1Parameter1\":\"2\"}{\"Object2Parameter1\":\"Added reader\",\"Object2Parameter2\":\"2\"}"
        string data = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(requestReader.ReadToEnd());

        //Splits the two json objects into a list of json objects
        var output = data.Split(new[] { '{', '}' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
              .Select(x => "{" + x + "}")
              .ToList();

        //Parse your json object
        foreach (var entry in output)
        {
            var parsedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(entry);
            foreach (var dataset in parsedObject.Properties())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dataset.Name);
            }
        }

        byte[] htmlBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Done");

        return new MemoryStream(htmlBytes);
    }
```